# double references to an object in java

Tags: java, object

there is a class:

```
public class Rectangle {
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public Point origin;

    public Rectangle(Point p) {
        origin = p;
    }
}
```

As it can be seen, the class has an object of the type Point. When I declare an object of the type Rectangle,

```
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne)
```

where originOne is of the type Point, then after the initialisation of the object, I will have two different references to the Point reference by originOne, namely rectOne.origin and originOne. What if I want to get rid of one of the variables for the sake of making the code safer ? Is there a way to do that other than writing the constructor in such a way that no extra objects are created ?

Comment: It's better to use `new Rectangle ( new Point ( x, y ) )`; then you have only one reference to the origin. (TIP: use a _getter_ method to access `origin` like `public getOrigint() { return origin; }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What if I want to get rid of one of the variables for the sake of making the code safer?

You are asking this in a strange way. I presume you want to make sure that someone can't affect `rectOne` by mutating `originOne` later.

> Is there a way to do that other than writing the constructor in such a way that no extra objects are created?

Your solution is in your question: create an extra object.

```
public Rectangle(Point p) {
    origin = new Point(p.x, p.y);
}
```

or

```
public Rectangle(Point p) {
    origin = p.clone();
}
```

It will have to support the `clone` method for this last one. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28Java_method%29) or another reference for what that involves.

If you want to do this without creating another object, (1) you probably can't, and (2) why are you restricting yourself from creating objects? That's kind of what what OO programming is all about.

---

You don't often have this same concern about `String`s. Why? Because they are immutable.

Another (IMO better) solution is to make the `Point` class immutable

```
public class Point { // possibly add "final class" 
    final int x;
    final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Now no one can mutate a `Point`, and your code becomes "safer".

Comment: But again, using the `clone()` returns a copy of the reference. Don't both the references get updated if one is changed?

Comment: @ambigram_maker, no. `clone()` returns a reference to a *new object*, which is (supposedly) "equal to" the old one. But it is a different object in memory. Changing one will not change the other.

Comment: OK... But `clone()` on an `ArrayList` returns a new `ArrayList` with the references of the objects right? (That's where I get confused)

Comment: @ambigram_maker, yes. It returns a *new* `ArrayList`. You are correct that it will have references to the same elements as the old `ArrayList`. If you wanted a new `ArrayList`, *and also* new elements, then you will have to do a deep copy; `clone` does a shallow one. But likely your `Point` class has references to primitives anyway, so this probably doesn't even matter in this case.

Comment: Hence... the primitive data types are exempted from updation... only the `Objects` are not. (Thanks @Paul) :-)

Comment: @ambigram_maker, just to be clear, primitive types (or their boxed counterparts, e.g. `Integer`) are not really a special exception in this respect. This is true of any immutable class, `Integer`, `String`, etc. Your own classes can have the same "behavior" (at least when it comes to this).

Answer (score 2):

When you use write your code the way you did it, there are no extra objects of `Point` class created, you just create a new reference to the same object stored in a new variable.

If you want to make sure you don't create an additional reference to the same `Point` object, you can pass X and Y of the point to your `Rectangle` class and create a new object in the constructor:

```
public Rectangle(int x, int y) {
    origin = new Point(x, y);
}
```

This way it makes it quite clear that you're not storing a reference to a passed parameter.